# How to Define a Macro that Returns Nothing

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, elisp

##### Background

I see the question [Best way to disable code](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76331/):

> I think something like the following would be nice:
>
> ```lisp
> (off
>   (global-set-key "\C-x" 'do-stuff)
>   (defun do-stuff () ...))
> ```
>
> I understand I can define `off` myself, but isn’t there a standard way to do this?

and [the corresponding answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/76332/39388) by [gigiair](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14046/):

> ```lisp
> (defun off (&rest args)
>   "Do nothing and return nil."
>   nil)
> ```

But I think this solution has 2 disadvantages considering that every function will **evaluate its arguments** and **return something**, for example (which is about "return something"):

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  (off '(display-time-mode   t)) ; ==> (), which is non-well-formed
  '(blink-cursor-mode nil))
```

Using the `off` function will lead to a non-well-formed *s-expression* (which is not expected by `custom-set-variables`).

---

##### Q

The key may be to define something that returns nothing, like:

```lisp
(defmacro erase-code (&rest pieces-of-code)
  ...)
```

which will make the last example expand to:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  '(blink-cursor-mode nil))
```

**In other words, it leaves nothing.**

---

Maybe the ultimate solution is not about *macro*, i don't know.

Essentially, I am asking: Is there anything that can *return nothing* or *leave nothing in place* in Common Lisp or Emacs Lisp?

Comment: "It would be nice to use an S-expression-based approach to comment some code."

Comment: Looks like `serapeum:comment` effectively returns nothing: https://github.com/ruricolist/serapeum/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#comment-body-body it `(declare (ignore body))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a macro which expands to nothing, since CL (and I think elisp) does not have what were sometimes called 'splicing macros'.  But you can very easily write a macro which expands to some fixed expression, for instance `nil`:

```
(defmacro off (&body forms)
  (declare (ignore forms))
  nil)
```

This is Common Lisp: the equivalent for elisp should be similar.  So then something like

```
(defun foo (x)
  (off
    (when x
      (explode-world)))
  x)
```

will not explode the world, and indeed there is no reference to `explode-world` in the macroexpanded code.